# Getting wrong count of number of page faults

Tags: c, operating-system, page-fault

I am trying to calculate number of page faults while reading a file of size 1kB to 1GB using C program on Linux. I am using below mentioned steps:

- I created a dummy file using

> dd if=/dev/zero of=file1.txt count=1024 bs=1024

- I flushed the pagecache using

> # sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

- I wrote a c program using getrusage() to calculate the number of page fault

> ```
> #include <sys/time.h>
> #include <sys/resource.h>
> #include <unistd.h>
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> int main() {
>   struct rusage usage;
>   //struct timeval start, end;
>   long int st,ed;
>   int i, j, k = 0;
>   getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &usage);
>   st = usage.ru_majflt;
>   FILE *fp;
>   int c;
>   int n = 0;
>   fp = fopen("file6.txt","r");
>   if(fp == NULL) {
>       perror("Error in opening file");
>       return(-1);
>   } 
>   while(!feof(fp)) {
>       c = fgetc(fp);
>   }
>   fclose(fp);
>   getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &usage);
>   ed = usage.ru_majflt;
>   printf("Started at: %ld \n", st);
>   printf("Ended at: %ld \n",  ed);
>   return 0;
> }
> ```

When I ran the code I got an unexpected output.

```
Started at: 0 
Ended at: 0
```

Where I went wrong?

Comment: Why do you expect page faults? Your code does not consume memory.

Comment: In your file loop you just keep overwriting `c`.  You are only using `sizeof(int)`, it is not reading the whole file into memory.  Also, page faults will vary depending on overall system memory consumption, i.e. other processes.

Comment: @rici can you write in answer how to bring complete file in buffer that would lead to page fault. I tried the same with fread() but still getting 0.

Comment: @cdarke any I idea how to calculate page fault only due to this operation?

Comment: @AkhileshYadav: on an empty machine it might load the whole lot into RAM and never have a page fault.  The number of page faults is not a constant for one particular program.  Try running multiple copies (hundreds) of the program at the same time, and slow them down a bit with some CPU activity.